# Hello, I am making a web scraping python script to iterate through the entire HTML. Right now It only takes the first one

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to screenscrape my schools menus off of there website.

I am having trouble making it iterate through the nested if statement below. Right now It only takes the first title, cal, and info but will not iterate through the rest of the HTML. Does anyone know how I could get the if statement to keep iterating?

Here is my python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://uc.campusdish.com/en/LocationsAndMenus/CenterCourt"

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')

table = soup.find_all('div', class_='menu__details')

titles = []
cals = []
infos =[]
#finds title, cals, and description in "Home Plates"
for item in table:
    if item.find_all('span', class_='item__name') is not None:    
        title = item.a.text
        titles.append(title)

        cal = item.find_all('span', class_='item__calories').text 
        cals.append(cal)

        info = item.find_all('p', class_='item__content').text
        infos.append(info)
print(titles)
print(infos)
print(cals)
```

Comment: When I run this code, I get an error that states: File "main.py", line 21
    cal = item.find_all('span', class_='item__calories').text 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    cal = item.find_all('span', class_='item__calories').text 
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 2160, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Do you not get that error?

Comment: find_all returns an array of items. You could specify the item using index e.g item.find_all('span', class_='item__calories')[0].text or (the better solution) is use find to return 1 item e.g: item.find('span', class_='item__calories').text

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from prettytable import PrettyTable

table = PrettyTable()
table.field_names = ['Name', 'Calories', 'Content']


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    target = soup.findAll("li", id=True, class_="menu__item item")
    for tar in target:
        try:
            table.add_row([tar.a.text, tar.select_one("span.item__calories").text,
                           tar.select_one("p.item__content").text])
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    print(table)


main("https://uc.campusdish.com/en/LocationsAndMenus/CenterCourt")
```

```
+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   Name                   |   Calories   |                                                           Content                                                           |        
+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+        
|        Grilled Lemon-Herb Pollock        | 190 Calories |                                   Grilled Pollock seasoned with lemon, garlic and oregano                                   |        
|        Herb Roasted Red Potatoes         | 100 Calories |                           Roasted quartered red potatoes tossed with rosemary, thyme and marjoram                           |        
|         Broccoli & Kale Stir-Fry         | 60 Calories  |                             Stir-fried kale, broccoli and garlic tossed with soy sauce and honey                            |        
|            White Dinner Roll             | 110 Calories |                                                    Soft white dinner roll                                                   |        
|               Apple Betty                | 200 Calories |                                  Warm apples with a crispy brown sugar-cinnamon crumb crust                                 |        
|           Chicken Caesar Salad           | 330 Calories |                          Grilled chicken, Parmesan and seasoned croutons on a bed of crisp romaine                          |        
|               Garden Salad               | 140 Calories |                            Egg, tomato, cucumber, carrot and bell pepper on a bed of mixed greens                           |        
|               Greek Salad                | 210 Calories |                          Tomato, feta, cucumber, banana peppers, Kalamata olives, onion and romaine                         |        
|               Garden Salad               | 15 Calories  |                            Fresh iceberg, romaine, cucumber, plum tomato, carrot and bell pepper                            |        
|          Chocolate Chip Cookie           | 120 Calories |                                  Freshly baked chewy cookie with semisweet chocolate chips                                  |        
| Gardenburger(R) Black Bean Veggie Burger | 270 Calories | Hearty black bean burger made with brown rice, onions, corn, red bell peppers, chilies and a hint of garlic on a white roll |        
|           Margherita Sandwich            | 420 Calories |               Fresh tomato, mozzarella topped with pesto sauce & parmesan crisps on toasted whole wheat bread               |        
|           Baked Russet Potato            | 140 Calories |                                                  Oven-roasted russet potato                                                 |        
|           Crispy French Fries            | 150 Calories |                                                Piping hot crispy French fries                                               |        
|               Sugar Cookie               | 120 Calories |                                               Freshly baked soft sugar cookie                                               |        
|            Cavatappi Alfredo             | 350 Calories |                                        Cavatappi pasta tossed in creamy Alfredo sauce                                       |        
|               Tossed Salad               | 30 Calories  |                  Crisp romaine lettuce tossed with fresh cucumber, carrot, onion and light Italian dressing                 |        
|            Vegan Mac & Cheese            | 470 Calories |                       Elbow macaroni baked with creamy Daiya(R) cheddar cheese sauce and bread crumbs                       |        
|           Zucchini & Tomatoes            | 40 Calories  |                                             Fresh zucchini with stewed tomatoes                                             |        
|         Vegan Peach-Banana Cake          | 310 Calories |                        Vegan blueberry banana cake topped with sweetened peaches and whipped topping                        |        
|         Chipotle Turkey Sandwich         | 530 Calories |                                Turkey, Monterey Jack, lettuce, tomato, onion & chipotle mayo                                |        
|      Turkey, Ham & Swiss Croissant       | 220 Calories |                      Turkey, ham, Swiss cheese, lettuce, tomato and honey mustard on a flaky croissant                      |        
|               Italian Sub                | 570 Calories |                          Ham, salami, provolone, banana peppers, lettuce and tomato with olive oil                          |        
|     Grilled Vegetable & Hummus Wrap      | 190 Calories |                   Grilled eggplant and zucchini, hummus, tomatoes, arugula and onion wrapped in a tortilla                  |        
|          Tandoori Chicken Wrap           | 340 Calories |             Tandoori-spiced chicken, pickled carrot and radish, cucumber and lettuce with curry yogurt dressing             |        
|             Signature Chips              | 140 Calories |                               Crispy potato chips seasoned with a blend of peppers and garlic                               |        
|           Oreo(R) Thimble Cake           | 110 Calories |                      Moist devil's food cake with Oreo cookie pieces topped with an Oreo yogurt mousse                      |        
|      Chicken & Rice Soup Florentine      | 80 Calories  |                     Chicken, rice, spinach, carrot, celery and onion simmered in a hearty chicken broth                     |        
|           Roasted Corn Chowder           | 150 Calories |             Roasted corn, diced potatoes and onions in a creamy rich soup spiced with herbs and hot pepper sauce            |        
|             Potato Leek Soup             | 130 Calories |                    Velvety puree of potatoes, leeks, onions, celery and herbs simmered in vegetable broth                   |        
|       BBQ Pineapple-Ham Flatbread        | 480 Calories |                            Ham, grilled pineapple and onions, Cheddar, pepper jack and BBQ sauce                            |        
|           Classic Cheese Pizza           | 270 Calories |                                              Mozzarella cheese and pizza sauce                                              |        
|             Pepperoni Pizza              | 300 Calories |                                            Pepperoni, mozzarella and pizza sauce                                            |        
|          Chocolate Chip Cupcake          | 210 Calories |                   Freshly baked yellow cake topped with creamy vanilla icing and semisweet chocolate chips                  |        
|          Chocolate Chip Cookie           | 120 Calories |                                  Freshly baked chewy cookie with semisweet chocolate chips                                  |        
|          Apple Stuffed Pancakes          | 240 Calories |                 Pancakes rolled and filled with apple compote and topped with cinnamon honey yogurt drizzle                 |        
|         Hash Brown Potato Patty          | 150 Calories |                                              Crispy fried shredded potato patty                                             |        
|          Chocolate Chip Cookie           | 120 Calories |                                  Freshly baked chewy cookie with semisweet chocolate chips                                  |        
|              Belgian Waffle              | 260 Calories |                                                 Crispy, golden-brown waffle                                                 |        
+------------------------------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```